# How to access nopcommerce website from an other website ?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, nopcommerce

I want to install **nopcommerce**. Domain of the this website is like shop.mydomain.com. And I want to access this shop from other website as www.exampleshop.com.

I will **get categories and products** from shop.mydomain.com. And then I will **show returned values** on www.exapleshop.com.
If customers add some product in shopping cart, I will save them in session.After that If customer give an order, I will send needful information to shop.mydomain.com.

What is the best way to do this mechanism. How can I do it? Is there any example like this ?

Answer (score 0):

The session is connected with the cookie, and the cookie with the domain name, so when you try to store the cart on session (that is not good idea anyway) and move from the one domain to the other the session will be lost, and so the cart.

So the example as you describe it can not be work.

What a store do when you try to add a product in the cart when is not on the final domain, is that understands it and redirect him on a page that double ask the user if he still won to add the product on the cart - but now is on the final domain.

Comment: Session is an idea, I can use other things but the problem is not this. Example : I can write web service that has some functions getCategory, getProductWithCategoryName .... I will add webservice referance to www.exampleshop.com site and I use it. I ask how can I do it ? Thanks.

Comment: @CevatUzun For me, you can not do that, is not good user interface, you going to have more problems and bugs than the one you try to avoid. At the end you need to pass what ever parameters you select from the one site to the other. I do not see any store on the internet that do that. Anyone. Too many bugs, too many problems, too many security issues, avoid it.

Comment: I use some content management tools in my websites. I do not want to change these codes. But some times my customers want to sell 10 20 pruducts. So I want to provide this tool without changing their structure. I want to install nopcommerce and access to it from my customer's site.

Comment: @CevatUzun I have understand what you ask for - I say you again, is not practical - in my opinion. The only thing that you can do is to add a link to the final page that make the order inside the store.